# I can't figure out how systemd integrates on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I am currently migrating my development platform to Ubuntu Xenial and I can't figure out how Ubuntu is integrating the init.d scripts with systemd.  For example look at this only fashioned service restart for MariaDB included in the base repository.

```
    root@xenial:/etc/init.d# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
    [ ok ] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

I looked in the script and I can't see how it calls systemd at all.  So what kinds of hacks is it doing to make it integrate "(with systemctl)"?

This brings me what I'm really trying to do is to be able to pass in an arguments with systemd.

So in total how far along is Ubuntu Xenial's init integration of systemd or is it really just a series of hacks for backwards compatibility.  I was expecting to find that everything had been converted to these new service files.

Answer (score 2):

The `init.d` scripts source some bash function from LSB  package

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Which load other ones from other packages

```
# Include hooks from other packages in /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
for hook in $(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null); do
    [ -r $hook ] && . $hook || true
done
```

Where systemd inject its own redirection

```
~$ dpkg -S /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd 
systemd: /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd
```

**Note:** Found using `strace /etc/init.d/.. status`